# Array of objects, length remains zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

TLDR: Does this console info make sense: Array[0], length 4 (objects)

I'm parsing a csv file.  This should produce an array of objects.  It sorta does, but the result seems odd to me.  I've got 2 arrays:

```
var array1 = JSON.parse(someDataFromBackEnd);
var array2 = [];

d3.csv('dots.csv', function(err, data){
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    array2.push( data[i] );
    //array2[i] = data[i]; //also tried
  }
});
```

Firefox DE Console ([See Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn01J.png)):

```
array1:  Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]
array2:  Array [ ]
```

Inspecting array2 shows 4 objects (see pic).  Array2 doesn't work with my code (while array1 does).  Array2[0] is undefined.

In both arrays the objects contain lat-long data (array1 has additional properties, FWIW):
[ {'long':120, 'lat':45}, {...}, {...}, {...} ]

My spidey sense tells me I'm missing something obvious here, but... ?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the the values in `array1` and `array2`. You can `console.log(array1);` to get the output.

Comment: We need more code to help you out.

Comment: your code looks right. Can u debug into the callback function and make sure data is an array? if you don't know how to debug, you can just print some alert("") calls and make sure the loop is executing.

Comment: Is `.csv()` asynchronous? Are you checking the console before or after the callback is called?

Comment: ^^ this is correct

Comment: Re: async, if I set "var csvData = d3.csv(...) and log it I get a promise (Object { header: d3_xhr/xhr.header(), mimeType: ...), but since I'm pushing the results into an existing array, that shouldn't be an issue, right?  Re: other questions, I'll update my post.  Thanks everyone.